# how i left join value from select query as table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have sql query to select values from multi table.

I used left join , but I have a problem.

I want to left join another table, but the problem is that this table name is about the value of column in the same query.

This is the query :

```
SELECT tags_assign.*,COUNT(*) AS total from tags_assign
  LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_assign.tags_id 
  LEFT JOIN tags_assign.module module ON module.id = tags_assign.module_id 
  WHERE tags.name = 'music theory';
```

When I execute this query , this error appears :

> SELECT command denied to user 'jason'@'62.100.08.01' for table
>   'module' database_tags_assign.sql

So how do I solve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

The user you are authenticated as (the one you passed to the `connect` function) does not have permission to `SELECT` from that database or table. You need to go into your control panel and authorise the username to do that, or you are using the wrong username/password.

Comment: the query work wen i remove this "LEFT JOIN tags_assign.module module ON module.id = tags_assign.module_id"

Comment: Do you have permission to access the `tags_assign` database? Is there such a database? Or did you mean to write `left join tags_assign as module on module.id = module_id`

Comment: Hello , what i want from sql is to use tags_assign.module value as column in left join , beacuese tags_assign.module is a column and it's value is about a table in the same database , but my problem here that database see tags_assign.module in left join as a table name so it don't return it's value to use it as true table name;

Answer (score 0):

My guess is all there tables are in the same database and there is a typo in the query:

```
SELECT tags_assign.*,COUNT(*) AS total from tags_assign
  LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_assign.tags_id 
  LEFT JOIN tags_assign module ON module.id = tags_assign.module_id 
  WHERE tags.name = 'music theory'
```

That is, instead of `tags_assign.module module` just use `tags_assign module`.'  My guess is that there is no tags_assign database.

Comment: Hello , what i want from sql is to use tags_assign.module value as column in left join , beacuese tags_assign.module is a column and it's value is about a table in the same database , but my problem here that database see tags_assign.module in left join as a table name so it don't return it's value to use it as true table name;

Comment: MySql does not allow you to dynamically specify tables in a join.  You need to re-think how you are representing the data.